# Gradient of Greens function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics

This question is about Jackson's equation (10.75) and (10.77) I don't know the step in between these two equations.I'm not sure what our unit vector $n'$ will be here and how can we take gradient of Helmholtz Green function: $$G(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}')=\frac{e^{|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'|}}{|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'|}. \tag{10.76}$$  and here are the quations $$\psi(\textbf{x})=\oint_s [\psi(\textbf{x}')\textbf{n}'.\nabla'G(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}')-G(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}')\textbf{n}'.\nabla'\psi(\textbf{x}')]da']\tag{10.75} $$$$\\ \psi(\textbf{x})=-\frac{1}{4 \pi}\oint_s\frac{e^{ikr}}{R}\textbf{n}'.[\nabla'\psi+ik(1+\frac{i}{kR})\frac{\textbf{R}}{R}\psi]da' \tag{10.77} $$

Comment: could you maybe insert the equations from the book since they are not available to everyone otherwise? or is your question only about taking the gradient of this Green function.

Comment: And note that Jackson has various editions where things moved around so your Chapter 10 may not be the same as mine (although mine is at work and I'm not).